# bash string as argument for executable in quotes

Tags: bash, arguments, echo, double-quotes

im sure this is simple. ive' tried a number of possibilities with no luck.

im seeking to execute the following in shell.

```
 ./secondexecutable -t "A string with spaces" -s "Another string with spaces" -o outfile.txt
```

the issue is that the executable takes a string from one executable and then applied to a second one. 
the second executable needs quotes (single or double) in order to preserve spaces.

```
tmp=`./firstexecutable`

echo $tmp   prints out the following     -t "A string with spaces" -s "Another string with spaces"


./secondexecutable $tmp -o outfile.txt
```

the shell truncates the argument so its basically akin

```
 ./secondexecutable -t "A" -s "Another" -o outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible design, in my opinion. Once you concatenate multiple strings with spaces into a single strings, there's no easy way to separate them without falling back to `eval`

```
eval ./secondexecutable "$tmp" -o outfile.txt
```

*might* do it, but beware of the risks with eval'ing arbitrary strings

---

If you can, you should re-work the first executable. If it could just return the **values** for the -t and -s options, your life would be much easier. For example, if it could even output the values on separate lines, like this:

```
A string with spaces
Another string with spaces
```

You could do this:

```
{ IFS= read -r t_option; IFS= read -r s_option; } < <(./firstexecutable)
./secondexecutable -t "$t_option" -s "$s_option" -o output.txt
```

Or, if the two values are not somehow correlated, get the first executable to calculate one at a time

```
./second -t "$(./first -t)" -s "$(./first -s)" -o output.txt
```

Comment: thanks. ill try eval. but no design here. its output from the first executable.

Comment: but why do you have an executable that returns an option string? As you can see, you run into problems with embedded quotes being mere characters. Do you have any control to re-work the first executable to simply return the values for the -t and -s options?

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the variable in your script:

```
./secondexecutable "$tmp" -o outfile.txt
```

Here's what happens when you do and don't use quotes:

```
$ cat countargs 
#!/bin/sh

echo $#
$ var='O HAI I IZ A VAR'
$ ./countargs $var
6
$ ./countargs "$var"
1
```

Comment: actually i tried the double quotes. perhaps the quotes inside the quotes is a problem.